# Проверка на пустоту полей формы

Tags: php

Есть форма, которая состоит из более чем десятки инпутов. Как написать функцию, которая будет одним махом проверять на пустоту все эти поля? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) 
    if(strlen($value)==0) 
        echo"Поле $key - пустое";
```

Comment: Круто! А если в посте будут другие переменные? Не из формы? Ты выберешь всех их и скажешь пользователю где пустые поля?

Comment: переменные адресной строки падают в $_GET; если форма method=post, то ВСЕ её поля упадут в $_POST. У меня в конструкторе форм есть здоровый конфиг с свойствами каждого поля в массиве, и по признаку обязательности идёт проверка.
Вообще, лучше проверку сначала делать на клиенте, через <input required> или JS ухищрения (для не-HTML5 браузеров)

Comment: Вы не поняли, поля упадут в POST, но как быть с $_POST['my_var'] = 'Hello lol!'; или $_POST['test_word'] = '     '; ?

Comment: На худой конец, иметь заранее подготовленный список ключей, которые нужно проверить, и пробежаться уже по нему

$formfields=array('name','phone','text');

foreach($formfields as $key) if($_POST[$key])...

Ещё можно сделать _POST многомерным, т.е.:

<input name="form[name]"> упадёт в $_POST['form']['name']

Comment: Так-то лучше. Я к тому что перебирать в прямую POST массив - это зло.

Answer (score 1):

Timophey Lanevich, лучше `!empty`

Comment: !$value
!isset($value)
empty($value)
strlen($value)==0

есть много способов проверить, пустая переменная, или её нет совсем

Comment: @Timophey Lanevich isset проверит, существует ли переменная или нет. Ей пофиг на содержание.